# How to add extensionless files to VSIX MEF editor extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I created a MEF editor extension (VSIX) for VS2012 using the information from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242(v=vs.110).aspx

Syntax highlighting, statement completion, signature help, and outlining features are working fine.

The way the editor extension links the file extensions with the content is as follow:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372313(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[Export]
[FileExtension(".hid")]
[ContentType("hid")]
internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition hiddenFileExtensionDefinition;
```

I cannot find a way to link a few specific extensionless files to the content type. How can I do this?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Don't specify file-exgtension and inside your textViewCreationListener, do a if-check if IDocument.FilePath has no extension, and then use SetContrntType or something?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris Eelmaa suggestion I found the solution to this issue. It might not be the best way to do it, but at least I solved the problem.

So, here is, I created a new class as follows:

```
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
class ExtensionlessViewCreationListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
    [Import]
    internal IEditorFormatMapService FormatMapService = null;

    [Import]
    internal IContentTypeRegistryService ContentTypeRegistryService = null;

    [Import]
    internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider = null;

    #region IWpfTextViewCreationListener Members

    void IWpfTextViewCreationListener.TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
        DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
        string docName = dte.Documents.Item(dte.Documents.Count).Name;
        if (docName.ToLower() == EditorConstants.DICTIONARY_FILE_NAME)
        {
            var contentType = ContentTypeRegistryService.GetContentType(EditorConstants.LANGUAGE_TYPE);
            textView.TextBuffer.ChangeContentType(contentType, null);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Cheers